# convergence radius of composition of power series

Tags: calculus

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ have radius of convergence $R_1=1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_nx^n$ have radius of convergence $R_2=2$. What can you say about the radius of convregence of:

$\mathit{i)}$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2a_n+b_n)x^n$;
$\mathit{i)}$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt{n}a_n+b_n)x^n$;
$\mathit{i)}$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n+\sqrt{|b_n|})x^n$;

Unfortunatly I've never saw exercises like this and do not know where to start. Of course I can say that the radius is *at least* $1$ but nothing more. How can I manipulate the series If i know nothing about the general $a_n$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the same notation you used, I give you some preliminary results:

First: the radius of convergence of $\sum_n (a_n+b_n)x^n$ is $\min \{ R_1, R_2 \}$. To verify this split this series in the sum of two series, and note that this series is convergent only in the case that both original series are convergent.

Second: if C is a constant, the radius of convergence of $\sum_n C(a_n)x^n$ is $R_1$. This is trivial.

Third: The radius of convergence of $\sum_n |a_n| x^n$ is the same as $\sum_n a_n x^n$. This can be proved using the formula $R_1^{-1}= \limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$.

Fourth: In general the formula $R_1^{-1}= \limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ is very useful. It allows you to compute the other radiuses.